# YouTube Analytics and Reporting API Bulk Reports CSV file has no values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I want to get the Bulk Report for "content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1" in Youtube's Reporting API.

I created a report making job with the `jobs.create` method in the official YouTube APIs Explorer.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs/create

A few days later, I got the URL of the report with the method `jobs.reports.get` in the APIs Explorer as well, gave Bearer's access token and issued a get request to the URL to download the CSV.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports/get

However, I could only get a header of the following format, although it should contain data.

```
date,channel_id,video_id,claimed_status,uploader_type,country_code,estimated_partner_revenue,estimated_partner_ad_revenue,estimated_partner_ad_auction_revenue,estimated_partner_ad_reserved_revenue,estimated_youtube_ad_revenue,estimated_monetized_playbacks,estimated_playback_based_cpm,ad_impressions,estimated_cpm,estimated_partner_red_revenue,estimated_partner_transaction_revenue
```

Of course, I got the token with the content owner's account and also entered the ID in onBehalfOfContentOwner and made an API request.

I have also confirmed that the revenue is being generated from the channel analytics page in Youtube Studio.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: hi did you resolve this, the documentation seems to be really sparse in this as to why its not returning values. I'm facing the same issue.